# Can this be expressed in point free style?

Tags: f#, lambda-calculus, pointfree

Given the following expression to sum an IEnumerable of numbers:

```
let sum l = l |> Seq.reduce(+)  //version a
```

is it possible to eliminate the argument--like so?

```
let sum = Seq.reduce(+)    //version b
```

I get an error from the F# compiler (FS0030) and I seem to recall having seen something about an "eta conversion" being involved but unfortunately my knowledge of lambda calc is too limited to follow how eta conversion is involved.

Can the argument be eliminated as in version b?

Would someone please point me to literature that would explain an eta conversion and how it would come into play in this particular piece of code?

FS0030:

> stdin(1,5): error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'sum' has been
>   inferred to have generic type
>       val sum : ('_a -> int) when '_a :> seq     Either make the arguments to 'sum' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be
>   generic, add a type annotation.

Comment: What does `l` do in version a? Can you please remind us (in the question body) what is `FS0030`?

Comment: Did you mean `let sum l = Seq.reduce (+) l` for version a?

Comment: Well, as you can see from the error (and probably know), F# doesn't allow generic values. Point-free style is only limitly supported in F#.

Comment: @petebu thanks--code is fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Eta conversion" simply means adding or removing the argument. The problem you are hitting is called value restriction. In ML languages, a value declared as a value, ie. declared without explicit arguments, cannot have a generic type, even if it has a function type. [Here](http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction#_why_the_value_restriction_exists) is some relevant literature. The idea is to prevent a ref cell from holding values of different types. For example, without value restriction, the following program would be allowed:

```
let f : 'a -> 'a option =
    let r = ref None
    fun x ->
        let old = !r
        r := Some x
        old

f 3           // r := Some 3; returns None : int option
f "t"         // r := Some "t"; returns Some 3 : string option!!!
```

As kvb said, if you do not intend the function to be generic, then you can add a type signature and use point-free style.

Comment: Maybe simply stated as: functions in ML languages can be closures, and since ML is statically typed, you must disambiguate the types in the referencing environment before use.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in point free style, but you need to add a (monomorphic) type annotation:

```
let sum : int seq -> int = Seq.reduce (+)
```

Comment: Thanks @kvb; I was also wondering if someone could point me to a bit more information on eta conversion.

Answer (score 5):

A point-free function is a value.
As other answers say, F# does not allow generic **values**. However, it perfectly allows generic **functions**. Let's convert `sum` into a function by adding a fake `unit` parameter:

```
let sum_attempt1() = Seq.reduce (+)
let v1 = [1.0; 2.0]     |> sum()    // float
// inferred by first usage:
// val sum_attempt1: unit -> (seq<float> -> float)
```

This works, although it is not yet generic. Marking the function `inline` does the trick:

```
let inline sum() = Seq.reduce (+)
// val sum: unit -> (seq<'a> -> 'a)

// Use
let v1 = [1; 2]         |> sum()    // int
let v2 = [1.0; 2.0]     |> sum()    // float
let v3 = ["foo"; "bar"] |> sum()    // string
```

Comment: Interesting thought--adding the inline on the function.