# OCaml type-system subtlety: polymorphism, pointfree reverse, and nested lists

Tags: types, functional-programming, polymorphism, ocaml

If I define a reverse function likeso:

```
let reverse =
  let rec helper out = function
    | [] -> out
    | a :: l -> helper (a :: out) l
  in helper []
```

Then `reverse (List.map reverse xs)` does not type-check, with error

```
Error: This expression has type 'a list list
   but an expression was expected of type 'a list
   The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list
```

But defining it with an explicit argument

```
let reverse l =
  let rec helper out = function
    | [] -> out
    | a :: l -> helper (a :: out) l
  in helper [] l
```

makes things work.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original definition:

```
# let reverse =
    let rec helper out = function
      | [] -> out
      | a :: l -> helper (a :: out) l
      in helper [];;
val reverse : '_a list -> '_a list = <fun>
```

is subject to the semi-famous value restriction because it has the form of an application (i.e., `helper []`) rather than a lambda.

The second definition has the form of a lambda, which is not subject to the value restriction.

Everything else follows from this.

The value restriction has been discussed many times on Stack Overflow. Here is one such discussion: [The value restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507448/the-value-restriction). The short summary is that some kind of restriction on making types polymorphic is required in the presence of mutable values (such as references). The value restriction is a kind of compromise that's easy to remember without being *too* restrictive.

When I start forgetting what the value restriction is all about (which happens periodically) I often refer to this paper: [Jacques Garrigue, Relaxing the Value Restriction](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/garrigue-value_restriction-fiwflp04.pdf)