# Type variables in a simple component

Tags: compiler-errors, polymorphism, ocaml, reason, reason-react

Say I have this simple component

```
type evt =
  | NoOp;

type t('a) = 'a;

let component = ReasonReact.reducerComponent("TestComponent");

let make = _children => {
  ...component,
  initialState: () => "hello",
  reducer: (evt, state: t('a)) =>
    switch (evt) {
    | NoOp => ReasonReact.NoUpdate
    },
  render: self => <div> {str("hello")} </div>,
};
```

(try it [here](https://reasonml.github.io/en/try?rrjsx=true&reason=ATAuE8AcFNmg3UwC8AoEIA%20wByB7AeUgG5V0wpZQAKAcgEMBKFYB08gG2iQGM8BbSHgB20YUmTAAStHoBnETPo9QAOgBO0ACYBXHtHUBhAUNHjqAIgAq0OaGOCRY0BcbsQXJP3oBrWJIB9HgALAEsOLU1hFAA%20YABvchBVFL5HM1AAGiTgUOFQ0FD6DgBlUHpQaAAuYGpmZDiLYOgODjwLbIxgTV19dRrqBCzgOwrqsDomepickDkAdwKQ2qHmRK6sXEJIWOlZBWElFVV8AFVILTHZ4ABfToworQMauRaAM12AHi1Q%20Dj4pQHI5qOzqPIAc0szVa7UYN2AnwA9D8-vcbsQgA))

Why am I getting

`The type of this module contains type variables that cannot be generalized`

? (The type variable is useless here, but imagine it was needed in initialState. Tried to keep the sample as simple as possible.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technical reason is that a ReasonReact component is record type which would look something like this:

```rust
type fauxComponent = {
  reducer: (evt, t('a)) => t('a),
  render: t('a) => ReasonReact.reactElement
};
```

If you try to compile this you'll get an error about an "Unbound type parameter". The difference in error is because it is inferred to be of type `ReasonReact.component` which has a bunch of type variables, one of which is inferred to have a polymorphic type. The problem is essentially the same, but much easier to illustrate without all the indirection.

Th technical reason why you can't do this I think is called [the value restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507448/the-value-restriction). But there are practical reasons as well. You actually can make this type compile if you explicitly specify `'a` as being polymorphic:

```rust
type fauxComponent = {
  reducer: 'a. (evt, t('a)) => t('a),
  render: 'a. t('a) => ReasonReact.reactElement
};
```

This says that `'a` can be anything, but that's also the problem. Since it can be anything, you can't know what it is, and you therefore can't really do anything with it other than to have it pass through and returned. You also don't know that  `'a` is the same in `reducer` and `render`, which isn't usually a problem with records since they're not stateful objects. The problem arises because ReasonReact "abuses" them as if they were.

So how would you then accomplish what you're trying to do? Easy, use a functor! ;) In Reason you can parameterize modules, which are then called functors, and use that to specify the type to use across the entire module. Here's your example functorized:

```rust
module type Config = {
  type t;
  let initialState : t;
};

module FunctorComponent(T : Config) {
  type evt =
  | NoOp;

  type t = T.t;

  let component = ReasonReact.reducerComponent("TestComponent");

  let make = _children => {
    ...component,
    initialState: () => T.initialState,
    reducer: (evt, state: t) =>
      switch (evt) {
      | NoOp => ReasonReact.NoUpdate
      },
    render: self => <div> {ReasonReact.string("hello")} </div>,
  };
};

module MyComponent = FunctorComponent({
  type t = string;
  let initialState = "hello";
});

ReactDOMRe.renderToElementWithId(<MyComponent />, "preview");
```

The parameters a functor takes actually need to be modules, so we first define a module type `Config`, specify that as the parameter type, and then when we create our `MyComponent` module using the functor we create and pass it an anonymous module that implement the `Config` module type.

Now you know why a lot of people think OCaml and Reason's module system is so awesome :) (There's actually a lot more to it, but this is a good start)