# type inference of (>>)(>>) (function composition)

Tags: f#, type-inference

I have seen somewhere (sorry, I can't find the a reference) this operator composition:

```
(>>)(>>)
```

where `(>>): (('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'c)` - `(>>)` is [the function composition operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233229.aspx).

I find simpler examples are easy to understand. For example `(>>)f`, where `f: i -> i`.
`(>>)(i -> i)` becomes `(i -> 't) -> i -> 't`. This is because `('a -> 'b)` is curried away, `'b`  is inferred to be `i` and `'t` remains a generic type.

I do not fully understand `(>>)(>>)`:

**The use**

What would `(>>)(>>)` and `(<<)(<<)` used for?

**Why it is necessary to make the argument explicit?**

```
> (>>)(>>);;

  (>>)(>>);;
  -^^^^^^

C:\Users\...\Temp\stdin(3,2): error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'it' has been inferred to have generic type
    val it : (((('_a -> '_b) -> '_c -> '_b) -> '_d) -> ('_c -> '_a) -> '_d)    
Either make the arguments to 'it' explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.
```

As suggested by the error message:

```
> let strangeFun arg = (>>)(>>) arg;;

val strangeFun : arg:((('a -> 'b) -> 'c -> 'b) -> 'd) -> (('c -> 'a) -> 'd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been several explanations of value restriction around here in the past; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117877/can-this-be-expressed-in-point-free-style/19118257#19118257) is one I wrote that explains why it is necessary. For completeness I'll copy here the example code that would be incorrect if the value restriction was removed:

```
let f : 'a -> 'a option =
    let r = ref None
    fun x ->
        let old = !r
        r := Some x
        old

f 3           // r := Some 3; returns None : int option
f "t"         // r := Some "t"; returns Some 3 : string option!!!
```

As far as what `(>>)(>>)` would be used for, I admit I don't know. There is however a similar-looking but useful function, which is `(<<) << (<<)` (better known in Haskell as `(.).(.)`), which returns a similar composition operator whose second and returned functions can take *two* arguments instead of one.

```
let (<<<<) f = ((<<) << (<<)) f;;

// val ( <<<< ) : f:('a -> 'b) -> (('c -> 'd -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'd -> 'b)
```