# Why is compiler ok with not closed generic?

Tags: f#

I have this code:

```
open System

let func<'t when 't:comparison> (a: 't[]) = a

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let array = [||]
    let actual = func array
    printfn "array = %A, actual = %A, same objects: %b" array actual (Object.ReferenceEquals(array, actual))
    Console.ReadKey()
    0
```

When I try it in LinqPad5 I get a reasonlable error:

> Value restriction. The value 'actual' has been inferred to have
>   generic type     val actual : '_a [] when '_a : comparison     Either
>   define 'actual' as a simple data term, make it a function with
>   explicit arguments or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add
>   a type annotation.

However, when I successfully (!) compile and run it (checked for full .NET Framework and DotNetCore both Debug/Release) in Visual Studio I get this output:

> array = [||], actual = [||], **same objects: false**

The only way I could expect this result if `'t[]` were a value type, but it is definitely not. So, WTF?!?

Decompiled assembly contains this code:

```
[CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.Module)]
public static class Program
{
  public static t[] func<t>(t[] a)
  {
    return a;
  }

  [EntryPoint]
  public static int main(string[] argv)
  {
    FSharpTypeFunc fsharpTypeFunc = (FSharpTypeFunc) new Program.array\u00409();
    IComparable[] comparableArray = Program.func<IComparable>((IComparable[]) fsharpTypeFunc.Specialize<IComparable>());
    FSharpFunc<object[], IComparable[]>.InvokeFast<bool, Unit>((FSharpFunc<object[], FSharpFunc<IComparable[], FSharpFunc<bool, Unit>>>) new Program.main\u004011(ExtraTopLevelOperators.PrintFormatLine<FSharpFunc<object[], FSharpFunc<IComparable[], FSharpFunc<bool, Unit>>>>((PrintfFormat<FSharpFunc<object[], FSharpFunc<IComparable[], FSharpFunc<bool, Unit>>>, TextWriter, Unit, Unit>) new PrintfFormat<FSharpFunc<object[], FSharpFunc<IComparable[], FSharpFunc<bool, Unit>>>, TextWriter, Unit, Unit, Tuple<object[], IComparable[], bool>>("array = %A, actual = %A, same objects: %b"))), (object[]) fsharpTypeFunc.Specialize<object>(), comparableArray, object.ReferenceEquals((object) (object[]) fsharpTypeFunc.Specialize<object>(), (object) comparableArray));
    Console.ReadKey();
    return 0;
  }

  [Serializable]
  internal sealed class array\u00409 : FSharpTypeFunc
  {
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    internal array\u00409()
    {
    }

    public override object Specialize<a>()
    {
      return (object) new a[0];
    }
  }

  [Serializable]
  internal sealed class main\u004011\u002D2 : FSharpFunc<bool, Unit>
  {
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public FSharpFunc<bool, Unit> clo3;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    internal main\u004011\u002D2(FSharpFunc<bool, Unit> clo3)
    {
      this.clo3 = clo3;
    }

    public override Unit Invoke(bool arg30)
    {
      return this.clo3.Invoke(arg30);
    }
  }

  [Serializable]
  internal sealed class main\u004011\u002D1 : FSharpFunc<IComparable[], FSharpFunc<bool, Unit>>
  {
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public FSharpFunc<IComparable[], FSharpFunc<bool, Unit>> clo2;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    internal main\u004011\u002D1(FSharpFunc<IComparable[], FSharpFunc<bool, Unit>> clo2)
    {
      this.clo2 = clo2;
    }

    public override FSharpFunc<bool, Unit> Invoke(IComparable[] arg20)
    {
      return (FSharpFunc<bool, Unit>) new Program.main\u004011\u002D2(this.clo2.Invoke(arg20));
    }
  }

  [Serializable]
  internal sealed class main\u004011 : FSharpFunc<object[], FSharpFunc<IComparable[], FSharpFunc<bool, Unit>>>
  {
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public FSharpFunc<object[], FSharpFunc<IComparable[], FSharpFunc<bool, Unit>>> clo1;

    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    internal main\u004011(FSharpFunc<object[], FSharpFunc<IComparable[], FSharpFunc<bool, Unit>>> clo1)
    {
      this.clo1 = clo1;
    }

    public override FSharpFunc<IComparable[], FSharpFunc<bool, Unit>> Invoke(object[] arg10)
    {
      return (FSharpFunc<IComparable[], FSharpFunc<bool, Unit>>) new Program.main\u004011\u002D1(this.clo1.Invoke(arg10));
    }
  }
}
```

This line seems to be a culprit:

```
IComparable[] comparableArray = Program.func<IComparable>((IComparable[]) fsharpTypeFunc.Specialize<IComparable>());
```

If I remove `comparison` constraint `Specialize` uses `object` instead of `IComparable`.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Why does F# compiler of presumably older version dissallows such code, and the newer one make it work, but in a very unpredictable way.

Comment: What do you see as unpredictable?

Comment: That returned object differs from the passed one. Why call to `new IComparable[0]` instead of `Array.Empty<IComparable>()`.

Comment: Why do you think that the returned object should be the same object?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Would not this be expected from this code: `let func<'t when 't:comparison> (a: 't[]) = a` ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key thing that Fyodor mentioned in his answer is that the way F# handles generic values is tricky. You can see that by looking at the following code which compiles fine:

```
let oops () =
  let array = [||]
  array.[0] <- 'a'
  array.[0] <- 1
```

Of course, you cannot put both `'a'` and `1` in the same array! What happens here is that the compiler actually compiles `let array = [||]` as a generic function that returns a new empty array when you access it (with a specific instantiation).

Note that this is possible only for simple values that are created without any side-effects. For example, if you wanted to print a message each time the array is accessed, it would not work. The following:

```
let oops () =
  let array = printfn "Creating!"; [||]
  array.[0] <- 'a'
  array.[0] <- 1
```

Gives a type error:

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
>       char but here has type
>       int

This is because the inference engine realised that it cannot compile `array` as a generic function and, instead, specialized the type based on the first use.

In your case, specializing the type would not cause any problem, because you are not using the generic value with multiple different types. This means that you can make the value the same by adding a side-effect to the creation - or even just ignore a unit value `()` - which is enough to make the compiler specialize the type:

```
let func<'t when 't:comparison> (a: 't[]) = a

let same () =
  let array = (); [||]
  let actual = func array
  printfn "same: %b" (Object.ReferenceEquals(array, actual))

let notSame () =
  let array = [||]
  let actual = func array
  printfn "same: %b" (Object.ReferenceEquals(array, actual))

notSame()  // same: false
same ()    // same: true
```

I guess if someone ever decides to make a Wat talk about F#, this would be a good candidate! The compiler could just disallow all generic values (which is what other ML languages do), but that would remove some useful constructs like `Array.empty` and replace them with `Array.createEmpty ()`.

Comment: That's probably the most difficult part of F# after C#. =) Always trying to understand how functional code is transformed to .NET OOP representation.

Comment: "This is because the inference engine realised that it cannot compile array as a generic function and, instead, specialized the type based on the first use." Why is this? Is this a general feature of generic functions - that they cannot have side effects? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here...

Comment: @sebhofer Generic functions can have side-effects, but generic _values_ cannot. I do not know how exactly the compiler checks for this, but I suppose an expression of the form `<expr>; <value>` is interpreted (purely syntactically) as possibly having a side-effect.

Comment: Interesting. Is there an obvious reason why they can't?

Comment: @sebhofer Side-effects in generic values can cause things to be wrongly typed. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117877/can-this-be-expressed-in-point-free-style/19118257#19118257

Comment: Thanks for the example @Tarmil!

Answer (score 5):

So, as I've gathered from the comments, your actual question was this:

> Why is it that returned object differs from the passed one?

**First of all,** the expectation of referential identity for values that are logically "equal" is vastly overrated. If your program relies on referential identity, you're doing it wrong. If you have to force referential identity to be preserved everywhere, you end up with Java.

Indeed, try this:

```
> obj.ReferenceEquals( 5, 5 )
it : bool = false

> obj.ReferenceEquals( [1;2;3], [1;2;3] )
it : bool = false
```

Huh?

Of course, you may end up with `true` in some special cases, for example:

```
> let l = [1,2,3]
> obj.ReferenceEquals( l, l )
it : bool = true
```

But that's merely a coincidence arising from the specific implementation that the compiler chose to represent your code. Don't rely on it.

**Secondly**, your function *does*, in fact, return the "same" (in referential identity sense) object. Try this:

```
   > let x =
         let array = [||]
         let typedArray : int[] = array
         let actual = func typedArray
         obj.ReferenceEquals( actual, typedArray )
   x : bool = true
```

See how the "malfunction" disappeared as soon as I created an intermediate `typedArray`? You can even replace `int` with `IComparable`, it will still be `true`.

The secret is that the function `func` is actually fine: it does return the "same" object.

The creation of a new object happens not inside `func`, but every time you reference `array`.

Try this:

```
> let x = 
     let array = [||]
     obj.ReferenceEquals( array, array )
x : bool = false
```

Huh? WTF?!

This happens, because `array` is not actually an object, but a *function* behind the scenes. Because you didn't specify what type `array` was, it must be *generic* - i.e. have any type that the user wants it to have. This must work:

```
let array = [||]
let a : int[] = array
let b : string[] = array
```

Clearly, `array` cannot have type `int[]` and type `string[]` at the same time, so the only way to implement such construct is to compile it as a *function* that takes no value parameters, but a single type parameter. Kind of like this:

```
static a[] array<a>() { return new a[0]; }
```

And then use that function to construct `a` and `b`:

```
var a = array<int>();
var b = array<string>();
```

And this is exactly what the compiler does. A function that takes only type parameters, one might call it "type function" in this context. And indeed, that's what it's called in compiled code - `FSharpTypeFunc`.

Comment: It’s still not clear why this function creates new instance of immutable object. If it were call to `Array.Empty` semantics won’t change, but literal of empty array of a given type would be always same object. What’s the point of not doing it?

Comment: Moreover, as soon as you explicitly specify the type of array everything starts working as expected. Literal becomes just a literal, though still initialized via `new T[0]`.

Comment: Yes, `Array.Empty` appeared in framework not long ago, but it looks like earlier versions of F# compiler even won't let you have this code in the first place. ;-)

Comment: This mechanism is more general than just arrays.